# Looking for the monaco-editor (?) movable panels

Tags: frontend, web-frontend, monaco-editor

I would like to use the moveable and drag&drop-able panels from vs-code (or Compiler explorer / godbolt.org) in a small web application (typescript, vite). Do they by any chance belong to the monaco editor or where can I find them?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, these editor group panels are a feature from Visual Studio Code.